Why is this inequality true for odd polynomials?
Let the polynomial $P(x)$ of odd degree $d$ be given by
$$x^d+a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+...+a_0$$
Let $A = |a_0|+ ... + |a_{d-1}| + 1$
Then why is $$|a_{d-1}(-A)^{d-1} + a_{d-2}(-A)^{d-2} +...+ a_0| ≤ (A-1)A^{d-1}$$
I can understand why $$|a_{d-1}A^{d-1} + a_{d-2}A^{d-2} +...+ a_0| ≤ (A-1)A^{d-1}$$
Using the  reasoning that $$(A-1)A^{d-1}$$
$$=|a_{d-1}|A^{d-1} + |a_{d-2}|A^{d-1}+...+|a_0|A^{d-1}$$
$$≥ |a_{d-1}|A^{d-1} + |a_{d-2}|A^{d-2}+...+|a_0|$$
$$≥ |a_{d-1}A^{d-1} + a_{d-2}A^{d-2}+...+a_0|$$
However I fail to see a similar reasoning for the other inequality.

$|a_{d-1}(-A)^{d-1} + a_{d-2}(-A)^{d-2} +\cdots+ a_0| \le |a_{d-1}|A^{d-1} + |a_{d-2}|A^{d-2}+ \cdots+|a_0| $, so the same argument works.

Sorry I still don't see immediately why this is true the reasons I found
$|{−1}()^{−1}+{−2}()^{−2}+⋯+{0}|≤|{−1}|^{−1}+|{−2}|^{−2}+⋯+|{0}|$ is because everything is positive and |a| + |b| + |c| ≤ |a +b +c|

It is just the triangle inequality (and $A$ is positive).

ok so I am assuming the triangle inequality is |a| + |b| ≥ |a + b| and trying to rewrite
$|{−1}(−)^{−1}+{−2}(−)^{−2}+⋯+{0}|$=
$|{−1}()^{−1}+(-{−2}()^{−2})+⋯+{0}|$ which would be less than or equal to  $|{−1}|()^{−1}+|{−2}|^{−2}+⋯+|_{0}|$ right?

I have tried to answer your question. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

First apply the triangle inequality:
$$
|a_{d-1}(-A)^{d-1} + a_{d-2}(-A)^{d-2} +\cdots+ a_0| \le 
|a_{d-1}(-A)^{d-1}| + |a_{d-2}(-A)^{d-2}| +\cdots+ |a_0|
$$
Now simplify the right-hand side, using $A > 0$:
$$
|a_{d-1}(-A)^{d-1}| + |a_{d-2}(-A)^{d-2}| +\cdots+ |a_0|
= |a_{d-1}| \cdot |{-A}|^{d-1} + |a_{d-2}| \cdot|{-A}|^{d-2} +\cdots+ |a_0| \\
= |a_{d-1}| A^{d-1} + |a_{d-2}| A^{d-2} + \cdots + |a_0| \, .
$$
And this is (because $A \ge 1$)
$$
 \le |a_{d-1}| A^{d-1} + |a_{d-2}| A^{d-1} + \cdots + |a_0| A^{d-1}
= (A-1) A^{d-1} \, .
$$
Remark: This estimate holds for all polynomials of degree $d \ge 1$, the fact that $d$ is odd plays no role.
